# combine split `data.frame` back in original order

Tags: r, dataframe, split-apply-combine

How would I go about putting this split `data.frame` back together such that the original order is preserved?

```
tmp <- lapply(split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl), function(x) x)
```

My actual use-case involves a more complicated function. I need to split a `data.frame` by a factor, perform some per-group transformations, and then combine it back *in the original order*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you will have to do any further manipulation for more complex examples, but `unsplit` seems to do the job in the case of your identity transformation (`function(x) x`):

```
all.equal(mtcars, unsplit(tmp, mtcars$cyl))
#[1] TRUE
```